# PHP/MySQL : special characters problems following MySQL 5.7 migration

Tags: php, mysql

My hoster decided to migrate my database without notice from MySQL 5.5 to MySQL 5.7 , resulting in special characters problems on my website : for example the character "é" in database now displays "Ã©" on my website.

I can see in PHPMyAdmin that the charset of tables didn't change (still 'latin1_general_ci'), but their type is now InnoDB (it was MyISAM before the migration).

Absolutely no change was made on my side, in my code. The charset of my HTML pages is iso-8859-1. It has worked perfectly for years until this migration to MySQL 5.7.

Do you know what causes my issue and how I can resolve it ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: it's very bad that your tables holding utf-8 data are configured with latin1 charset. it's not the last time you will face the consequences. for the moment set charset from php to latin1

Comment: I already tried to add mysqli_set_charset($link, 'latin1_general_ci'); after the mysqli_select_db()... It makes no difference...

Comment: there is no such charset as latin1_general_ci